# Creating own widgets for rqt

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello again :)

I have one more question regarding documentation of rqt:
In the tutorial [Writing Python Plugin](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Python%20Plugin) there's a paragraph **3.2 Using a UI file**, which I don't really understand. It says:

> The example uses an Qt Designer UI
> file to describe the widget tree.
> Instead of hand-coding the widget tree
> the python_qt_binding.loadUi function
> creates the widgets at runtime based
> on the description from the file.

Does it mean that now I have to create a project with Qt Designer and afterwards just copy the .ui file?  (A project like based on an example **Creating a Qt Widget Based Application** ?) But how will all the functions copy themselves to Python?

I managed to write some simple widget based on rqt_robot_steering (and add it to RosGui :)), but I had to write all callback functions by hand. Is there a way of doing it automagically?

Cheers,
da-na

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65585/creating-own-widgets-for-rqt/) by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Does it mean that now I have to create a project with Qt Designer and afterwards just copy the .ui file? (A project like based on an example Creating a Qt Widget Based Application ?)
```

No it's not mandatory. There's another [rqt tutorial page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt/Tutorials/Using%20.ui%20file%20in%20rqt%20plugin) that explains (sorry the link was missing from python tutorial you cited); in a nutshell, it's up to developers to use `Qt Designer` / `.ui` files or not. Although personally I highly recommend using it for better maintenance, if you choose not to use `.ui` files in your `rqt` plugin, there's still [a portion of document about non-ui files](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt/Tutorials/Using%20.ui%20file%20in%20rqt%20plugin#Write_rqt_plugin_without_relying_on_.ui).

```
But how will all the functions copy themselves to Python?
```

That tutorial should explain the idea too.

```
I managed to write some simple widget based on rqt_robot_steering (and add it to RosGui :)), but I had to write all callback functions by hand. Is there a way of doing it automagically?
```

In `Qt` in general you use `Signal`-`Slot` feature for callback mechanism, which is applicable to `rqt` as well.

Please add comments / modify your OP if something is still unclear.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1